# C# VSTO Excel Task Pane not showing when embedding Excel in Word

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vsto

Currently I'm working on a Excel Add-In where the user can select an XML file. I read the XML and add nodes to a TreeView. This TreeView is placed within the Task Pane. When starting Excel on its own everything works, but when I add a Chart or an Embedded Excel in Word and open it in Excel, the Task Pane is not showing up.

This code eventually triggers the event for opening the TaskPane

```
private void ShowTaskPane_TglBtn_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
      Globals.ThisAddIn.TaskPane.Visible = ((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked;
}
```

This code opens the Task Pane for real:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    public UserControl1 taskPaneControl1;
    private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane taskPaneValue;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        taskPaneControl1 = new UserControl1();
        taskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneControl1, "Task Pane");
        taskPaneValue.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);
    }

    private void taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.ShowTaskPane_TglBtn.Checked =
            taskPaneValue.Visible;
    }

    public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane TaskPane
    {
        get
        {
            return taskPaneValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're experiencing is expected behavior. VSTO is not designed to work in "embedded" environments.

Comment: Do you know how I can achieve this? Even though I think the answer is 'no'

Comment: Have you tried accessing functionality over a Ribbon command?